# How to split an Array into 3 parts e.g int[] {8,3,6,2,9,5,1,7,4}. i am trying to write a mergesort method and i havve been stuck for over a day

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, merge

just a check to see if the array is split the left array gets split but the centre has no elemnts in it.
//i havent finished the code once i am able to split the array into three parts i can call the mergesort3 method to recursivley keep splitting it until there is no more items left to split.
then i can merge them using merge3 method.just a check to see if the array is split the left array gets split but the centre has no elemnts in it.
//i havent finished the code once i am able to split the array into three parts i can call the mergesort3 method to recursivley keep splitting it until there is no more items left to split.
then i can merge them using merge3 method.

```
public static int[] mergesort3(int[] arr) {

    int elements = arr.length;
    int mod = elements % 3;
    int div = elements / 3;

    int sizeLeft = div + (mod > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    int sizeCenter = div+ (mod > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    int sizeRight = div + (mod > 1 ? 1 : 0);
    int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, sizeLeft);
    int[] centre = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, sizeLeft+1, sizeCenter);
    int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, sizeCenter+1, sizeRight);

  

*****
but i am stuck on the first step of splitting this array into three different parts.
   //just to check if the array will print its values.
 for (int i = 0;i<left.length; i++){
        System.out.println(centre[i]);
    }
//i get a illegal arugment exception.

    return merge3(left, centre, right);
```

i have tried searching online for help but i am struggling i would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: In which line exactly do you get the exception? Have you tried debugging yet?

Comment: Why does your loop go until `i<left.length` if you are printing elements from the array `centre`? In this case it should be `i<centre.length`.

Answer (score 1):

`copyOfRange` expects the first index (inclusive) and the last index (exclusive) of the array.

Therefore passing `sizeCenter` and `sizeRight` as the last argument is wrong.

Therefore the splitting should be as follows:

```
int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, sizeLeft);
int[] centre = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, sizeLeft, sizeLeft + sizeCenter);
int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, sizeLeft + sizeCenter, arr.length);
```

From Javadoc:

> **int[] java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(int[] original, int from, int to)**
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **original** the array from which a range is to be copied
>
> **from** the initial index of the range to be copied, inclusive
>
> **to** the final index of the range to be copied, exclusive.(This index may lie outside the array.)

P.S. you don't need a loop to print your arrays. Just use `System.out.println (Arrays.toString (left));`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can do via Java 8 :

```
int[] array = {8,3,6,2,9,5,1,7,4};

        int size = array.length / 3; // to get the size of 3 subarrays

        int[][] subarrays = IntStream.range(0, 3)
                .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.copyOfRange(array, i * size, (i + 1) * size))
                .toArray(int[][]::new);

        for (int[] subarray : subarrays) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subarray));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing the wrong indices to the array of range method.

Try using this

```
int sizeLeft = div + (mod == 1 ? 1 : 0);
int sizeCenter = div + (mod == 2 ? 1 : 0);
int sizeRight = div + (mod == 2 ? 1 : 0);
int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, sizeLeft);
int[] centre = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, sizeLeft, sizeLeft + sizeCenter);
int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, sizeLeft + sizeCenter, sizeLeft + sizeCenter + sizeRight);
```